# Is client-side java intrinsically less secure than javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, security

Much has been made of a series of bugs and exploits on client side java, leading to the blacklisting of various versions by apple, mozilla, etc.  Yet javascript is an even less controlled language without static typing.  Today javascript allows for many of the same potential problems: local storage, accessing data in different windows, opening connections to servers (though not arbitrary sockets).

Is it simply that javascript is better tested, with a community including many browser vendors, is it that javascript is somewhat more limited, without sockets for example, or is javascript, in fact, just as vulnerable as java?

Comment: The browser runs Javascript - it's fully under the browser's control. The behaviour and restrictions placed upon client side javascript are fully documented and tested. Java runs in its own VM; the browser has no control. So whilst it's essentially the same problem, browsers are heavily tested and used by everyone, applets are less tested and used by very few people. Further, applets can access and modify the local filesystem if allowed to; Javascript never can...

Comment: What is client-side java for you ? Something run by a JRE or an applet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a matter of *language*. It's a matter of *environment*.

Running Java applets on a web page currently involves using a Java plug-in, which takes a JVM that includes features to do all kinds of things we wouldn't want a web page to be able to do and runs code in that JVM in a "sandbox" to prevent it doing those things. The JVM still has the features, the environment (the plugin) just tries to deny access to them, and the browser has to fully trust the plugin to do that, as it has no control over what the plugin does once it loads it. (This is the nature of NPAPI plugins.) There's been a history of the plugin's sandbox being compromised, and to make matters worse, the update process was clunky and users tended not to keep up with security patches. Since it *seems* like it's the browser's fault when the plugin gets compromised (it isn't), browser vendors are trying to phase out Java in the browser. Google also claims that their latest architecture for Chrome makes supporting NPAPI difficult.

In contrast, running JavaScript on a web page involves the browser running JavaScript code in its **own** embedded environment that it (the browser) has full control over, giving it strictly limited access to a small number of browser-controlled features designed from the start (in the case of the modern features) to deny malicious use. The "attack surface" (as security folks put it) is dramatically reduced, and responding to those attacks is fairly directly under the browser vendor's control. You can see how browser vendors would prefer that scenario.

Browsers can be compromised too, of course, which is why browser vendors push so hard to get us to accept automatic updates.

---

Side note: It would have been entirely possible for browser vendors to build a designed-for-security-from-the-start, limited-subset JVM directly into the browser, just as they've built a JavaScript VM into them (through the V8, SpiderMonkey, etc. projects), and have the same degree of control over it. They just didn't. Instead, they focussed on taking JavaScript forward.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, as it's a logical answer.

Comment: I was researching different javascript attacks.  I think one thing java has going against it is the monolithic nature of it.  Attack java and you can get everyone's computers, regardless of CPU type, or OS.  Javascript is more fragmented, so it's less attractive as a target

Comment: @Dov: True, there are really only, what, two major JVM implementations? (Oracle's and OpenJDK, which I think have a *lot* of code in common.) And only the two plugins (Oracle's and IcedTea). Whereas there are ~4 major JavaScript implementations (more if you count the JScript rewrite between IE8 and IE9 and JavaScriptCore)...